# unable to ping 8.8.8.8 with wireless connection on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: 20.04

installed Ubuntu 20.04 with wired connection, then i tried changing to wireless by going into /etc/netplan and changing the settings based off https://netplan.io/examples/#connecting-to-a-wpa-personal-wireless-network example. Now i am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 and install any of the components i need.

sudo lshw -C network :

```
  *-usb:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       vendor: Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC)
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.1.1
       logical name: eth0
       version: 3.00
       serial: b8:27:eb:7f:9d:65
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: usb-2.10 ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=lan78xx link=no maxpower=2mA multicast=yes port=MII speed=480Mbit/s
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: b8:27:eb:2a:c8:30
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.202 firmware=01-72f6ece2 ip=192.168.1.207 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml :

```
ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "Fios-CL7hd":
                    password: "203406112"
            dhcp4: true
            addresses: [192.168.1.207/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.204
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

don't have a interfaces directory

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to ask Ubunbtu. Please share your interface details (see the comment below).
If you have e.g. wifi and ethernet you have to chooce from which device you want to ping e.g. `ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: i tried the command and still am unable to connect to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Can you show your routes? `sudo ip r s` or `sudo ip route show`